# Unload an xml file and load a new xml file using MouseEvent.CLICK event listener in AS3

Tags: xml, actionscript-3

I am working on a project where I'm creating a list of buttons using an XML. When you press one of those buttons, a new xml is loaded which creates 'sub buttons' as you may.

With the code I wrote, everything works, except for when I press a top-level button (first-level button), it loads the xml which creates sub-buttons and loads some text data but when I press another top-level button, it loads the new xml, creates sub-buttons, loads different text data,.......BUT, old sub-buttons are also there....

I want to be able to remove the old sub buttons. I have googled but I couldn't get any help :/ Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The code starts from when top-level buttons have been created and a CLICK MouseEvent has been assigned to those buttons.

```
function onButtonClick(me:MouseEvent):void {
    xmlLoader.load(new URLRequest(bookElement.xmllink.toString()));
    xmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onSubXmlLoad);
}

function onSubXmlLoad(e:Event):void {
    trace("xml loaded");
    new_sub_xml = new XML(sub_xmlLoader.data);
    var Books:XMLList = new_sub_xml.name.books;
    var len:int = Books.length();
    trace(len + " Books");

    for (var i:int = 0; i < len; i++) {
            sub_btn = new SubFeatureButton();
            sub_btn.x = 10 + i * 50;
            sub_btn.y = 90;
            addChild(sub_btn);
            sub_btn.name = "sub_btn" + i;
            sub_btn.buttonMode = true;
            trace(sub_btn + i);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably should create a container for your sub nav buttons, also keeping references to those buttons in some sort of array would make things easier.

The code below should work

```js
var subNav:Sprite = new Sprite();
subNav.x = 0;
subNav.y = 0;//put the right values here
addChild(subNav);

function onButtonClick(me:MouseEvent):void {
    xmlLoader.load(new URLRequest(bookElement.xmllink.toString()));
    xmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onSubXmlLoad);
}

function onSubXmlLoad(e:Event):void {
    trace("xml loaded");
    new_sub_xml = new XML(sub_xmlLoader.data);
    var Books:XMLList = new_sub_xml.name.books;
    var len:int = Books.length();
    trace(len + " Books");

    while(subNav.numChildren >0)
    {
        subNav.removeChildAt(0);
    }

    for (var i:int = 0; i < len; i++) {
            sub_btn = new SubFeatureButton();
            sub_btn.x = 10 + i * 50;
            sub_btn.y = 90;
            subNav.addChild(sub_btn);
            sub_btn.name = "sub_btn" + i;
            sub_btn.buttonMode = true;
            trace(sub_btn + i);

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked. I knew I had to remove the old sub buttons before creating the new ones I just didn't know how to get there.

It worked perfectly except for that I had to change 'subNav.childNum' to 'subNav.numChildren'. Again, thank you so much for the help.